# Replace argument N in previous command

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, command-history

I've recently migrated to ZSH, and I'd like to get a bit more efficient at substituting arguments in commands. Specifically, I'd like to replace argument "N" in the most recent invocation of command "cmd". I don't want to know what the previous argument pattern was, I just want the entire argument to be replaced.

For example, say I have this command somewhere in my history,

```
foo arg-1 arg-2 arg-3
```

And I want to replace the first positional argument with "arg-replaced" on my next invocation. Looking through `zshexpn`, I thought I could do something like:

```
!foo:1:s/.*/arg-replaced/ [TAB]
```

With the expected results:

```
foo arg-replaced arg-2 arg-3
```

But that results in an error, "zsh: substitution failed".

I looked at the question "[How do I replace a specific argument of a previous command in zsh?](https://superuser.com/questions/762582/how-do-i-replace-a-specific-argument-of-a-previous-command-in-zsh)" and it seems almost what I want, except that it only replaces the previous command, rather than searching up the history for my command pattern. I feel like this should be something supported by default zsh expansion, but I'm darned if I can figure out how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `!foo:1` evaluates to `arg-1` and nothing else. So, that's not what you're looking for.

Secondly, [as the documentation states](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Overview), history expansions do not nest. So, there's no way to take the whole history line `foo arg-1 arg-2 arg-3` and then replace it's second argument with something in just one expansion statement.

However, having said that, there are two ways to get what you want.

## Option 1: String replacement

If you know the actual value of the argument you want to replace, then you can just replace that. This is simple:

```
!foo:s/arg-1/arg-replaced
```

## Option 2: Actual argument replacement

Since we cannot nest history expansions, we cannot replace an argument by index in one substitution. However, nothing prevents use from using several history expansions in the same command line:

```
!foo:0 arg-replace !foo:2*
```

---

Both of these evaluate to `foo arg-replace arg-2 arg-3`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply on an old question.